# form does not return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as soon as I send the form, it does not return the values I want. i'm using ajax to receive the data.

```
                         <form action="registro-de-dominios.php" method="POST" id="ajax-form" class="form-inline">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName2">WWW</label>
                            <input type="text" class="p-3 form-control form-control-lg mb-2 mr-sm-2 input-ro www" id="inlineFormInputName2" name="www" value="www" placeholder="www." readonly>

                            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Domínio</label>
                            <div class="input-group justify-content-center mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" name="dominio" id="dominio" class="input-dom form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Digite o domínio desejado">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 select-padding">
                                <select name="point" id="point" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                                    <option value=".com">.com</option>
                                    <option value=".com.br">.com.br</option>
                                    <option value=".net">.net</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="salvar-form" class="btn btn-dominio btn-outline-danger" name="enviar" value="Enviar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            const www = $('.www').val();
            const dominio = $('#dominio').val();
            const com = $('#point').val();
            $("#salvar-form").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "registro-de-dominios.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        www: www,
                        dominio: dominio,
                        com: com
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        alert("ENVIANDO...");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('ok');

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('tente novamente');
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is what returns:

[image]

does not return anything in the "dominio" field and returns the ".com" option, even if I choose another option

Comment: what is the value of `$('#dominio').val()` ?

Comment: Remove `action="registro-de-dominios.php" ` from `form` and set `type="button"` for the `button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the `www`, `dominio`, and `com` consts outside the button click event handler. So they are only set once, while the document is loading, not when the button is clicked. So you are getting the default values in AJAX call. They should be assigned inside the click handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#salvar-form").click(function(e) {
            const www = $('.www').val();
            const dominio = $('#dominio').val();
            const com = $('#point').val();
            ...
        });
});
```